# GitHub Actions: Cache repo to speed up Maven builds

Tags: maven-3, github-actions

Maven dependencies are downloaded every time my build workflow is triggered.

Travis CI provides a way to cache Maven repositories. Does GitHub Actions provide similar functionality that allows caching Maven repositories?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently as of 10 September 2019 caching of build dependencies is not present in Github Actions. Github staff have acknowledged that this feature is necessary, and have replied that "We're working on caching packages and artifacts between workflow executions, we'll have it by mid-November [2019]."

Source: https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Caching-files-between-GitHub-Action-executions/m-p/30974/highlight/true#M630

Answer (score 36):

For completeness, this is an example of how to cache the local Maven repository on subsequent builds:

```
steps:
  # Typical Java workflow steps
  - uses: actions/checkout@v1
  - name: Set up JDK 11
    uses: actions/setup-java@v1
    with:
      java-version: 11
  # Step that does that actual cache save and restore
  - uses: actions/cache@v1
    with:
      path: ~/.m2/repository
      key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
      restore-keys: |
        ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
  # Step that runs the tests
  - name: Run tests
    run: mvn test
```

See [this page](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows) for more details.

Answer (score 9):

As of 2021, the most up to date official answer would be

```yaml
- name: Cache local Maven repository
  uses: actions/cache@v2
  with:
    path: ~/.m2/repository
    key: ${{ runner.os }}-maven-${{ hashFiles('**/pom.xml') }}
    restore-keys: |
      ${{ runner.os }}-maven-
```

taken from an official github example at https://github.com/actions/cache/blob/master/examples.md#java---maven

Comment: This is a near-duplicate of the top-voted answer.

Answer (score 8):

For maven you can now use `setup-java` to cache the dependencies. Example:

```yaml
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v2.3.1
      name: Install Java
      with:
        java-version: 8
        distribution: 'adopt'
        cache: 'maven'
```

Note that there are the same with other `setup-*`: `node`, `python` and `ruby`.

Answer (score 3):

Dependency caching is now available:

https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

Answer (score 2):

I started to use skjolber's Maven Cache Github Action, see https://github.com/marketplace/actions/maven-cache. My first tests are quite positive. The first build downloaded the dependencies from Maven Central; the subsequent build found the dependencies in the cache.

Answer (score 0):

For multimodule projects one could speedup builds by building only modules affected by the recent changes using https://github.com/avodonosov/hashver-maven-plugin/

This will work given the possibility to cache the local maven repository, as described in the @Rob van der Leek's answer.

`mvn install` the project artifacts after every build, and on the next build the hashver-maven-plugin will find artifacts of the unaffected modules and will skip them.